# I didn't apply enough DWR treatment to my jacket, can I just add more?

Tags: clothing, waterproofing, jackets

I went and applied grangers DWR treatment to my waterproof cycling jacket and put it in the dryer for a few minutes to set it. After my first couple rides, it appears there are a few small spots where it is wetting out immediately.

Can I simply wet the jacket and apply more DWR? Should I dry it in the dryer again? Or do I need to wash and re-proof?

Comment: in my experience (with nickwax) the stuff doesn't work. No matter how much you put one. Once a jacket is no longer waterproof... Perhaps you could try a commercial re-proofing service.

Comment: @ldgorman - Can you suggest any of these services in the U.S.?

Comment: DWR is *not* the main reason why jacket is waterproof (or not). In a breathable jacket it is usually a prerequisite for any moisture exchange to the outside, but as long as the main membrane and seams are intact, there still shouldn't go any water to the inside. It just feels wet, because the outer fabric is soaked (colder) and no moisture can go out (you get wet faster from your sweat). If your membrane is broken, DWR might help some, but it wont make it really waterproof again.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that I would try one or two inconspicuous spots where it appears to be wetting the exterior. Those spots may be resistant to your treatment for some reason. Try a spray waterproofing locally on those. The different formulation may penetrate better. If it doesn't work, you haven't ruined the jacket. You can always use the spray on boots or something.